# How to write UNIT-test for this PHP code on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

How to test this function?

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();

    return Response::json([], ResponseHttp::HTTP_OK);
}
```

I know that I must create several post delete it, but how it test?

Answer (score 0):

You may write something like this:

```
public function testDestroy()
{
    $post = factory(\App\Post::class)->create();

    $this->call('DELETE', "post/delete/{$post->id}");

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertNull(\App\Post::find($post->id));
}
```

Comment: public function testDestroy()
    {
        $post = factory(Post::class)->create([
            'id' => 1,
        ]);
        $this->delete('/api/posts/1');
        $this->assertNull(Post::find($post->id));
    }

Comment: test failed, but why?

Comment: delete func -public function destroy(Post $post)
        {
            $post->delete();

            return Response::json([], ResponseHttp::HTTP_OK);
        }

Comment: i would check this: first, does test goes to controller's destroy() function? you may dd(111) here. second, does controller code really working properly

Comment: you may place dd(111); (means die and dump) in controller. this will ensure that `$this->delete('/api/posts/1'); ` actually goes to this function (or may be incorrect request is sent)

Comment: so that in your route is may be not `DELETE` , but `POST` method or other

Comment: all work normal, but test failed. maybe has opportunity check result without "find" ?

Comment: what if after delete use GET and if result not found - test ok?

Comment: well, if the test tell that is not null... you may debug it by dd(Post::find($post->id));); this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

- the controller (the *system under test*) is called `Example\Controller\PostController`
- the model (or entity) used is called `Example\Entity\Post`

then the `PostController::destroy()` method can be tested as such:

```
use Example\Entity\Post;
use Example\Controller\PostController;
use Illuminate\Http;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testDestroyDeletesPost()
    {
        $post = $this->createMock(Post::class);

        $post
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('delete');

        $controller = new PostController();

        /** @var Http\JsonResponse $response */
        $response = $controller->delete($post);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Http\JsonResponse::class, $response);
        $this->assertSame(Http\Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertEquals([], $response->getData(true));
    }
}
```

#### What this test does

- it creates a test double for the instance of `Post` which we will later pass into `PostController::destroy()`
- it sets up the test double in such a way that we expect the method `delete()` to be called exactly once (not worrying about arguments, nor return value)
- it creates an instance of the `PostController`
- it invokes the method `PostController::delete()`, passing it the test double for `Post`, and capturing the return value in a `$response` variable
- it asserts that `$response`

  - is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse`
  - has an HTTP status code of `Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_OK`
  - has an empty JSON body

For reference, see:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html